# Turn two lists comprehensions into one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I am trying to create the `table_data` dictionary from Pandas dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Tom', 'Jack', 'Jill'],
    'Age': [42, 53, 18, 22],
    'City': ['London', 'New York', 'Bangkok', 'Warsaw']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

table_data = dict(
        headers = [[header] for header in list(df)],
        columns = [df[header].tolist() for header in list(df)],
)

print(table_data)
```

Is there any way to avoid iterating over `list(df)` twice and turn those two list comprehensions into one? 
Or does it defeat the purpose of list comprehension and I should use plain old `for` loop instead, like so?:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Tom', 'Jack', 'Jill'],
    'Age': [42, 53, 18, 22],
    'City': ['London', 'New York', 'Bangkok', 'Warsaw']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

headers = []
columns = []
table_data = {
    'headers': headers,
    'columns': columns,
}
for header in list(df):
    table_data['headers'].append([header])
    table_data['columns'].append(df[header].tolist())

print(table_data)
```

Comment: You don't need `list(df)`, use simply `df`. Conversion seems useless and probably takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by creating tuples first, then `zip` and convert tuples to lists:

```
L = [([header],df[header].tolist())  for header in list(df)]
h, c = zip(*L)

table_data = dict(
        headers = list(h),
        columns = list(c),
)
```

Non loop solution:

```
table_data = dict(
        headers = df.columns.to_frame().values.tolist(),
        columns = df.T.values.tolist(),
)
print(table_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
header = [list(df.columns.values)]
values = df.values.T
table_data = dict(headers=header, columns=values)
```

Comment: +1: while list comprehensions are an excellent tool in native Python, if you find yourself writing a lot of them when working with Pandas, Numpy etc. you are probably missing the point of using those libraries.